# What is the difference between a .py file and a .ipy file?

Tags: python, file, ipython

I've tried saving (and running) a script in both ways, and running it using both `ipython` and `python`, but I don't see any difference.  Are these filename extensions redundant?

---

Edit: [the difference between python and ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370457/what-is-the-difference-between-python-and-ipython)

Comment: @Madness that's not a good dupe target since the OP (and presumably anyone with the same question) is already aware of the difference in those two. From the question: "I tried... running it using both ipython and python."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782744/can-i-execute-ipython-scripts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045396/ipython-behavior-different-for-py-and-ipy-files-despite-script-being-pure-py

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`.ipy` indicates that it's an IPython script. The only difference between IPython scripts and normal Python scripts is that IPython scripts can use IPython magics, e.g. `%timeit`, and run system commands as `!echo Hi`.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting that you still (perhaps obviously...) have to call it using `ipython` (i.e. not just `python ___.ipy`)

Comment: I don't think that's anywhere close to happening :).