# What is the difference between a .py file and .ipynb file?

Tags: python

I have read about `.py` and `.ipy`, also the difference between python, ipython and notebook.

But the question is: what is the real difference between `.py` and `.ipynb` file?

Is `.ipynb` file just more convenient to be run on jupyter notebook, or anything more?   I am wondering because I am thinking about which format to be used for publishing on GitHub.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you publish. Do you want to publish an interactive workbook for learning experience or do you want to publish a library?

Comment: https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2256311/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-ipynb-extension

Answer (score 33):

`.py` is a regular python file. It's plain text and contains just your code.

`.ipynb` is a python notebook and it contains the notebook code, the execution results and other internal settings in a specific format. You can just run `.ipynb` on the jupyter environment.

Better way to understand the difference: open each file using a regular text editor like notepad (on Windows) or gedit (on Linux).

Save on git the `.ipynb` if you want to show the results of your script for didatic purposes, for example. But if you are going to run your code on a server, just save the `.py`

Comment: It is very helpful, thanks. I just seems like better to keep .py files on git.

Answer (score 13):

`py` means **PY**thon

`ipynb` means **I**nteractive **PY**thon **N**ote**B**ook - which is now known as Jupyter notebook.

The latter one is merely a Python script with descriptive contents - you describe what your data is doing by means of Python script and some funny texts. That's pretty much it - and also, you need a specific editor e.g. PyCharm or Google Collab to open and run it.

Answer (score 7):

Adding @Josir answer, the below information is very useful for **open** `.ipynb` file using **PyCharm**.

1. Create a new Python project in Pycharm
2. Specify a virtual environment, and install the jupyter package(`pip install jupyterlab`).
3. Run the server using the `jupyter-lab` command.
4. Browser will open the jupyter notebook like below, there you can execute the `.ipynp` file.
   [image]

Here is documentation https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32029027/11924650

> .ipy indicates that it's an IPython script. The only difference between IPython scripts and normal Python scripts is that IPython scripts can use IPython magics, e.g. %timeit, and run system commands as !echo Hi.

Comment: Thanks, I already read this part and I am learning the .ipynb, not .ipy.

Comment: Downvoted just because the answer is to the wrong question!