# Setup script from Github

Tags: python, github, anaconda, article

I found a interesting script on Github, however I need some help with the setup.
https://github.com/primakov/DuneAI-Automated-detection-and-segmentation-of-non-small-cell-lung-cancer-computed-tomography-images

So what I did so far was:
opening an Anaconda prompt, creating an virtual environment, in the virtual environment I installed all requirements. But then I do not know what to do. After the requirement installation step they say that I must be able to run the script. However I do not understand what to type/ do after pip install -r requirements.txt .

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: There is a notebook in the same directory as a demo of how to run the source: https://github.com/primakov/DuneAI-Automated-detection-and-segmentation-of-non-small-cell-lung-cancer-computed-tomography-images/blob/main/Automatic%20segmentation%20script/Automatic%20batch%20segmentation.ipynb - It should help with loading your first 'CoutourPilot' script

Comment: Do I need to run Automatic batch segmentation.ipynb? I am not that familiar with programming... Sorry if im asking silly questions.

Comment: Sure - The ipynb is like a runnable text editor. This one presents the code required to run the target script. You can run the ipynb if you wish https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/index.html - or use that file as an example to produce your own python script to run your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502484/what-is-the-difference-between-a-py-file-and-ipynb-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054672/how-to-save-code-file-on-github-and-run-on-jupyter-notebook?noredirect=1&lq=1